# Why isn't PRIVATE working as I expect when linking my executable against a library that links privately to another library?

Tags: cmake, linker

I wrote a small test project in order to to understand how the `PRIVATE` keyword works in cmake's `target_link_libraries()` function. We have a **main** target which links against a first library called **lib1**, and this first library in turn links against a second library **lib2**. The transitive handling of dependencies is in every case `PRIVATE`, so I expected **main** only to be able to access the function of **lib1** and similarly **lib1** only to be able to access the function of **lib2** (see graph and code below). Now in main we call a function from **lib2** directly. However, the project links and executes normally so I don't get it.

More in details, I thought that `target_link_libraries(lib1 PRIVATE lib2)` was populating the property of lib1 as `LINK_LIBRARIES=lib2` and `target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE lib1)` was populationg the property of main as `LINK_LIBRARIES=lib1` but the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARY` property of lib1 is not set to lib2 and so linking main against lib1 would not make lib2 accessible to main.

[image]

structure of folder

```
project(dependency_propagation) cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

add_library(lib1 src1.cpp) add_library(lib2 src2.cpp)

target_include_directories(lib1 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes) target_include_directories(lib2 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes)

target_link_libraries(lib1 PRIVATE lib2)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE lib1)
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <function2.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << function2() << endl;
    return 0; }
```

**src1.cpp**

```
int function1() {
    return 1; }
```

**src2.cpp**

```
int function2() {
    return 2; }
```

**function1.hpp**

```
int function1();
```

**function2.hpp**

```
int function2();
```

Comment: Because lib1 & lib2 share the same public include dir, preprocessor is able to resolve `#include <function2.hpp>` during compilation of `main.cpp`. Because lib1 is static, lib2 is also visible (it must be visible) while linking your executable.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes I understand that preprocessor is able to resolve the include for the reason you mention. But still the second point is not clear, I added something to my answer maybe you can consider explaining in more details?

Comment: Creation of a **static** library doesn't involve a *linking* step. So all libraries (`lib1.a` and `lib2.a`) are passed to the linked when the **executable** is built. In that respect (passing a static library file as a parameter to the linker) PRIVATE linkage has the same effect as PUBLIC.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, your comment made me understand the issue, thank you so much! Of course PRIVATE | INTERFACE | PUBLIC in target_link_libraries() is just specifying the transitive dependence for the linking process and not for the compiling process right? You can transform this in an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

You made both your libs have the same public include directory (I.e. both libs are sharing an include directory for their headers). If you don't want something that links to `lib1` to be able to include headers that are supposed to be for `lib2`, then don't put `lib1` and `lib2`'s headers under the same include directory- make it so that their headers are not reachable from the other's include directories.

Your libraries are static because you didn't specify whether they should be static or shared, and you didn't set [`BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html#variable:BUILD_SHARED_LIBS) to a truthy value. When specifying linkage against static libraries, CMake builds the `lib1` static library and the `lib1` static library, and then builds the executable telling the linker to link both those static libraries to the executable. If you're using C++ and you want something that's *not part of the interface* of a static library to be more private, you can declare and define it only in a non-header file inside an [unnamed namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces).